# Auto Add/Delete rows in joint table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have noticed that in many-to-many relationship, joint table is maintained by ef. i.e

```
Center 
ID     name
1      C1
2      C2

Facility
ID     Name
1      F1
2      F2

Center_Facitliy
CenterID    FacilityID
1             1
1             2
2             1
2             2
```

If I do

```
Center = GetCenterById(2);Indcluds Center_Facilities collection
Center.Center_Facilities = new List<Center_Facility> { 
                               new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 3 }, 
                               new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 1}    
                            }
```

this update Center_Facility table to

```
Center_Facitliy
CenterID    FacilityID
1             1
1             2
2             1
2             3
```

It automatically deletes 2-2 and adds 2-3. Could somebody explain why and how this happens?

This doesn't happen with below

```
CenterEmployee
ID   Name     Phone    CenterID
1    E1       123       1
2    E2       123       1
3    E3       123       2
```

(Employe can only work at one center)

```
Center = GetCenterById(1); //Indcluds CenterEmployee collection
Center.CenterEmployee = new List<CenterEmployee> { 
                               new CenterEmployee { Name=E5, Phone=123 }, 
                               new CenterEmployee { Name=E4, phone=123 }    
                            }
Result
CenterEmployee
ID   Name     Phone    CenterID
1    E1       123       null
2    E2       123       null
3    E3       123       2
4    E4       123       1
5    E5       123       1
```

It updated FK relation but didn't delete old record (1,2).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are updating `Center.Center_Facilities` as follows:

```
Center.Center_Facilities = new List<Center_Facility> { 
                               new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 3 }, 
                               new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 1}    
                            }
```

It means that you are replacing existing `Center_Facilities`(which has been loaded into context) collection in `Center` with a new `Center_Facilities` collection and that's why previous collection is being deleted and and the new collection is being added. That's the expected behavior of Entity Framework otherwise if your new collection contain a set of `Center_Facility` that already exists in the database then it will throw duplicate key exception.

Moreover now think that you don't want to replace but to add to the existing `Center_Facilities` collection then you have to do as follows:

```
Center.Center_Facilities.AddRange(new List<Center_Facility> { 
                                   new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 3 }, 
                                   new Center_Facility { FacilityID = 1}    
                                })
```

And in this case you have to make sure that the newly added collection does not contain any set of `Center_Facility` that already exists in the database.

Hope now its clear to you.

Comment: That makes sense but what triggers is this behavior? Can the same behavior apply to other relationship as well? I have other relationship table that doesn't have this behavior. Have updated original question to include this.

Comment: @Bhavesh is existing `CenterEmployee ` collection being loaded into context while you are assigning new `CenterEmployee` collection?

Comment: its on work machine but I will create new project this weekend and put it on github

Comment: Okay! I shall wait for that. Please mention me here.

Comment: could it be bcause second table is one-to-many while first one is many-to-many?

Comment: @Bhavesh Oh! Yes! That's the case! You should have mentioned it. In second case there is no chance of duplicate key as it has already auto-increment primary.

Comment: is there a way to for this behavior 1-* ?

Comment: @Bhavesh Did not understand your question please!

Comment: is there a way to have same behavior for scenario to CenterEmploye ( one-to-many relationship)

Comment: @Bhavesh Yes! Have.  Just call `Center.CenterEmployee.Clear()` before assigning the new collection.

Comment: that will only clear list for center and wont delete those records from table. Data will be left in table with FK set to null

Comment: No! it should also delete records from database table too.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that [2, 2] and [2, 3] are deleted, because you just told your `dbContext` that Center [2] only has center facilities with Ids [1] and [3].

You are right, a relational database management system implements a many-to-many relation using a separate table: the junction table. Normally the junction table has only the Ids of the connected items. Since the combination [CenterId, FacilityId] is unique, this combination is usually used as a primary key, which makes it really fast to query.

If you design a many-to-many relation in entity framework code first, you don't have to mention the junction table:

```
class Center
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Center offers zero or more facilities (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Factility> Facilities {get; set;}
}
class Facility
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // every Facility is offered at zero or more Centers (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Center> Centers {get; set;}
}
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Center> Centers {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Facility> Facilities {get; set;}
}
```

Note that the junction table is not mentioned!

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by non-virtual properties. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables.

Because of the two-sided virtual ICollection, entity framework can detect that you designed a many-to-many relationship and will automatically create a proper junction table for you, without attributes or fluent API.

**But how do I query without the junction table?**

Don't use the junction table, use the ICollections instead:

Give me (several properties of) the UK centers with (several properties of) their obsolete facilities:

```
var result = dbContext.Centers
    .Where(center => center.CountryCode == "UK")
    .Select(center => new
    {
        // select only the properties that you plan to use
        Id = center.Id,
        Name = center.Name,
        ...

        ObsoleteFacilities = center.Facilities
          .Where(facility => facility.Obsolete)
          .Select(facility => new
          {
              // again, only the properties you plan to use
              Id = facility.Id,
              ...
          })
          .ToList(),
     });
```

Entity framework knows your many-to-many and is smart enough to understand that for this a (group-)join with the junction table is needed.

Now if you've fetched Center [2] and Facility [3], it is easy to connect them, without having to worry whether there is already a relation between them:

```
var center2 = dbContext.Centers.Find(2);
var facility3 = dbContext.Facilities.Find(3);
// TODO: check if really found

// connect them:
center2.Facilities.Add(facility3);

// add a new facility:
center.Facilities.Add(new Facility() {...});
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Alternatively you could have added the center to the facility:

```
facility3.Centers.Add(center2);
dbContext.Facilities.Add(new Facility()
{
    ...
    Centers = new Center[] {center2},
});
```

The nice thing about this, apart from that this is very intuitive, is that you don't have to worry whether there is already a relation between center2 and facility3 or not.

The disadvantage is that you'll have to fetch the complete center and facility for this. Usually you will be querying data far more often than adding and updating, and changing relations is usually done after (relatively slow) user interaction, so I doubt whether this will ever be a problem.

But if you really want to add the relation without having to fetch the center and the facility first, you could add the DbSet that contains the junction table

```
public DbSet<CenterFacility> CenterFacilities {get; set;}
```

To add the relation:

```
dbContext.CenterFunctions.Add(new CenterFacility()
{
    CenterId = 2,
    FacilityId = 3,
});
```

But are you certain that there isn't already such a relation? You will have to fetch it first. And are you certain that the relation is not added by someone else between your fetching and your adding?

You see, so many problems, it's just not worth handling the junction table yourself!

Comment: agree, its lot easier with ef managing it for us. I was wondering if we could have similar behaviour for other one-to-many tables (see second example in question - CenterEmployee)